# Overlay click interaction issue

Tags: jquery, css, overlay

I have a hidden div which I use as an overlay for different features on a website. Initially the div is set to `display: none`.

The problem is that when the AJAX query returns it will return a simple form that has a button on it, when I click the button to submit the form it closes the overlay and doesn't process the form, I'm trying to find a way around this so that the `$("body").click(function(e) {` only affects outside of the `innerWrapper` div in the overlay.

Any help greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay" style="display: none"><div id="innerWrapper"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 10000;
}
#overlay #innerWrapper {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10001;
}
```

Now the jQuery code I'm using is:

```
$("#article").on("click", ".send", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var vAID = $(this).attr("data-cid");

    // Display overlay
    $("#overlay").css("display", "inline");

    $.ajax(
    {
        url : "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data : {id:1,aid:vAID},
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            $("#overlay #innerWrapper").html(data);
        }
    });

    e.stopPropagation();
});

$("body").click(function(e) {
    $("#overlay").slideUp("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if an element inside of the overlay have been clicked or if the event was out of this context. At the momentan the overlay will always close, when the user is clicking anywhere in the document. Change your click listener to this:

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    var $overlay = $("#overlay");

    if( $overlay.has($(e.target)).length < 1)
        $overlay.slideUp("fast");
});
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/utW4V/

`e.target` is the element the user was clicking on. When this element is not inside the overlay, we can savely close it.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to listen to click events on your overlay (since it is expanding to the width of the viewport) and stop the propagation of all click events when they reach your `#innerWrapper`:

```
$("#innerWrapper").click(function(e){
  // prevent unhandled clicks within the wrapper from
  // bubbling up
  e.stopPropagation();
});

// either listen on #innerWrapper and delegate events
// or manually add events here:
// e.g. ``$("article").on('click', '.send', function(){ /* ... */ });


// all clicks not within the wrapper will close the overlay
$("#overlay").click(function(e) {
    // handle all other clicks within the overlay
    $("#overlay").slideUp("fast");
});
```

**[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/numujato/1/edit)**